# Retrieve images from different PCs

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a website (HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript) which needs to have access to different PCs and getting images. Then I want to display those images to any user uses my program.

For example I want to open the folderA that is on pcA from my PC and get all the images in 
that folder and display them in my site. Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
$dir1 = "pictures/";
$dir2 = "pictures2/";
$dir3 = "pictures3/";

 $basedir = array(
    'basedir1' => $dir1 ,
    'basedir2' => $dir2 ,
    'basedir3' => $dir3 
   );

    function readGPSinfoEXIF($image_full_name)
    {
    if (file_exists($image_full_name) )
     {
       $exif=exif_read_data($image_full_name, 0, true);
       if ( !empty($exif['GPS']['GPSLatitude']) )
       {

         if(!$exif || $exif['GPS']['GPSLatitude'] == '') 
          {
           return false; 
          } 

          else 
           {
            $lat_ref = $exif['GPS']['GPSLatitudeRef']; 
            $lat = $exif['GPS']['GPSLatitude'];
            list($num, $dec) = explode('/', $lat[0]);
            $lat_s = $num / $dec;
            list($num, $dec) = explode('/', $lat[1]);
            $lat_m = $num / $dec;
            list($num, $dec) = explode('/', $lat[2]);
            $lat_v = $num / $dec;

            $lon_ref = $exif['GPS']['GPSLongitudeRef'];
            $lon = $exif['GPS']['GPSLongitude'];
            list($num, $dec) = explode('/', $lon[0]);
            $lon_s = $num / $dec;
            list($num, $dec) = explode('/', $lon[1]);
            $lon_m = $num / $dec;
            list($num, $dec) = explode('/', $lon[2]);
            $lon_v = $num / $dec;

            $gps_int = array($lat_s + $lat_m / 60.0 + $lat_v / 3600.0, $lon_s + $lon_m / 60.0 + $lon_v / 3600.0);

            return $gps_int;
           }//end of else
        }//end of if checking if GPS value is not empty
      }//check if file exists
    }//end of function

             function dirImages($dir) 
                {
                 $d = dir($dir);
                 while (false!== ($file = $d->read())) 
                    {
                     $extension = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.')); 
                     if($extension == ".jpg" || $extension == ".jpeg" || $extension == ".gif" |$extension == ".png") 
                     $images[$file] = $file; 
                    }
                    $d->close();         
                    return $images; 
                }

$COUNTER_IMAGE = 0;   

foreach ($basedir as $dir) // array of dirs path p.x pictures/
   {
        $array = dirImages($dir);
        $counter =count($array);

        $sql_ip = "SELECT dir FROM users WHERE dir = '".$dir."' ";
        $result_ip = mysql_query($sql_ip);
        $row_ip = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_ip);

        if(empty($row_ip['dir']) )
           {              
             //inserting user details
             $insert_user_details= @mysql_query("
                INSERT INTO users 
                VALUES(
                '', 
                '$localIP', 
                '', 
                '".$dir."',
                '".$data['latitude']."', 
                '".$data['longitude']."',
                '".$data['ipAddress']."',
                '".$data['countryName']."',
                '".$data['cityName']."'
                ) ");
            }

            $sql_user = "SELECT user_id FROM users 
            WHERE  dir ='".$dir."'  ";
            $result_user = mysql_query($sql_user);
            $row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_user);

            foreach ($array as $key) 
            {
                $image_full_name = $dir."/".$key; 
                $results = readGPSinfoEXIF($image_full_name);
                $latitude = $results[0];
                $longitude = $results[1];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM monument_info 
                WHERE monument_longitude='".$longitude."' AND monument_latitude ='".$latitude."'  ";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                                    if( ($longitude != $row['monument_longitude'])
                                    && ($latitude   != $row['monument_latitude']) 
                                    && empty($row['monument_longitude'])
                                    && empty($row['monument_latitude']) 
                                    )

                                    {
                                        //$COUNTER_IMAGE = $COUNTER_IMAGE + 1;
                                        $insert_monument_details= @mysql_query("
                                        INSERT INTO monument_info 
                                        VALUES(
                                        '".$row_user['user_id']."', 
                                        '$longitude', 
                                        '$latitude',
                                        '', 
                                        '',
                                        '".$image_full_name."'
                                        ) ");

                                        if (file_exists($image_full_name) )//This if statement hides a bug
                                            {
                                              echo "<img  src='".$image_full_name."'   widht=350 height='300' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                            }
                                    }

                                else
                                {
                                    if (file_exists($image_full_name) )//This if statement hides a bug
                                    {
                                        if( !empty($row['monument_longitude']) && !empty($row['monument_latitude']) )
                                        {
                                          echo "<img  src='".$image_full_name."'   widht=350 height='300' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
            }//end of foreach of printing images in folder
    }
```

Comment: Websites cannot access to clients. Do you mean uploading images?

Comment: No. A webserver cannot "reach out" and grab files from your local PC. Allowing such a thing would be a **HIDEOUS** security problem. A user can trigger an upload from their pc to your server, but not vice versa.

Comment: Are you using this in LAN ? Or are you trying to portforward some port and give a service ?

Comment: @MarcB TS hasn't stated the webserver is in a different LAN than the client PCs. Whilst your statement holds true in most hosted cases, it's certainly not a universal truth.